# Using PowerShell to extract data from a large tab-separated text file, masked it and then merge the masked data back to the original file

Tags: powershell

I am newbie to Windows PowerShell and wanted to know if is it possible to use PowerShell to extract specific data from tab-delimited(.dat) file and merge it back together to the original file.

The reason behind the extraction of data is that they are sensitive data and requires masking.

Upon extraction, I would require to mask the data and after masking, would require to merge this masked data again back to its original file on their specific places.

Please provide some pointers, any kind of help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Vishaka, please show examples of the code you have already tried, an example for how the file looks like (fake data is fine). This way you'll get more engagement on your question and avoid unnecessary flags.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

Here's a solution based on my limited understanding of your question (*if you add more details I may be able to be more specific*)

### Code

Seems all you need to do is read all the data, modify and write it to the file, so here it is!

```
$Columns = 2,4 # Columns to mask out (Indexes start from 0)

cat ./lol.dat | % {
    $arr = $_.split("`t")
    $Columns | % {$arr[$_] = '*'*$arr[$_].length}
    $arr.join("`t")
} | Out-File ./lol.dat
```